# Alter Table - What does this do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help explain the meaning of the following SQL statements.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentMonth] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [Fk_FinancialYear_PaymentMonth] FOREIGN KEY([FinancialYearId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[FinancialYear] ([FinancialYearId])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentMonth] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Fk_FinancialYear_PaymentMonth]
```

Is the first statement adding a foreign key constraint, called `Fk_FinancialYear_PaymentMonth`, to table PaymentMonth?

If so, why have `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentMonth] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Fk_FinancialYear_PaymentMonth]`?
And I can't find an explanation for REFERENCES.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag with the specific RDBMS you are using.

Comment: You have read the [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK` Specifies whether the data in the table is
> or is not validated against a newly added or re-enabled FOREIGN KEY or
> CHECK constraint. If not specified, WITH CHECK is assumed for new
> constraints, and WITH NOCHECK is assumed for re-enabled constraints.
>
> `{ CHECK | NOCHECK } CONSTRAINT` Specifies that constraint_name is
> enabled or disabled. This option can only be used with FOREIGN KEY and
> CHECK constraints.

[Microsoft Docs reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Can you please attribute and quote the parts that were lifted from documentation?